# Install Anaconda and access python for all users

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda for all the users on ubuntu 18.04. I installed anaconda at /root/anaconda3.
After that i edited the path in in /etc/environment to include the anaconda path. 
When i login as a user i can see the path as

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/root/anaconda3/bin:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

I dont know why the No such file or directory is showing up. 
when i try to run python it does not detect python.

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python3       
apt install python        
apt install python-minimal

Ask your administrator to install one of them.

You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

I want to use anconda's python. I am able to use anaconda python as root user but not as other users. how do i make it work for all users?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Typically, `/root` is the `root` user's home directory and is accessible to `root` user only. One way to overcome the issue is to change the permissions of this root directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /root
```

**Be warned though that doing this not advised since changing files that are critical to system may cause it to become unstable.**

---

Other way is to install anaconda in a different directory and assigning permissions to the install directory. The instructions to do that can be found on [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/) link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Never give 777 to any directory, and specially to root.